# Inconsistent spacing between multiple tables in pdf drawn via easytable

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am facing issue of inconsistent spacing between tables. I am using easyTable(v0.8.4) to draw multiple tables in a pdf along with Apache pdfbox(v2.0.23). I would like to have a consistent space difference of 10f between the tables spanning over multiple pages but this is not happening. Sometimes I get a table with correct spacing and sometimes the next table gets drawn on the new page, leaving a gap in the pdf between 2 tables. Please let me know how can I resolve this. Following is the code for drawing tables.Following is the image highlighting the issue faced:
[image: Spacing image]

```
public ByteArrayInputStream createPDF(String fileName, List<PDFElementsDTO> pdfElementsDTOList) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    final PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    document.addPage(page);
    float startY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 50f;
    List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<>();

    float[] columns = new float[1];
    float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - 2 * 50f;
    Arrays.fill(columns, width / 1);
    // table metadata
    TableBuilder typeBuilder = Table.builder().addColumnsOfWidth(columns).fontSize(12).font(HELVETICA).width(width);
    LOGGER.info("starting  pdf generation process for : " + fileName);
    typeBuilder.addRow(
            Row.builder().add(TextCell.builder().text("PDF- Header").horizontalAlignment(CENTER).build())
                    .backgroundColor(Color.BLUE).textColor(Color.WHITE).font(HELVETICA_BOLD).fontSize(12)
                    .horizontalAlignment(CENTER).padding(5f).build());

    tables.add(typeBuilder.build());

    addContentToTheTable(page, pdfElementsDTOList, tables);

    try (final PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
        for (final Table table : tables) {
            RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder().page(page).contentStream(contentStream).table(table).startX(50f)
                    .startY(startY).endY(50f).build().draw(() -> document, () -> new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4), 50f);
            startY -= (table.getHeight() + 10f);
            if (startY < 0) {
                startY = (page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 50f) - ((table.getHeight() + 10f));

            }
        }
    }
/*addHeader(document, fileNames);*/
    document.save(out);
    document.close();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Second thing which I am trying to do is to add header/footer on every page of the pdf but the same is also not visible. I would really appreciate any help if possible. This is what I tried but nothing was rendered.

```
private void addHeader(PDDocument document, String fileName) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getPage(i);
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
        PDPageContentStream contentStream    = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        float fontSize = 15.0f;
        contentStream.beginText();
        // set font and font size
        contentStream.setFont( font, fontSize);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(700, 1150);
        contentStream.showText( "header text");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        document.save( "file path" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a picture where we can see the first issue?

Comment: Hi @philonous, thanks for the response. I have added the link to the image.

Comment: Concerning your invisible header/ footer - the coordinates `700, 1150` are clearly off-page for a normalized A4 page.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for pointing that out. I am able to get the footer displayed on the pdf. Can you help me with the first issue as well?

Comment: I'm not really knowing *easyTable* but I find it peculiar that in your loop over the `tables` you build the table drawer for each `table` starting on the same `page` and the same `contentStream`, in particular as you mention that issues occur in context with tables drawn on new pages. I would assume that each time after drawing a table you should update the `page` and the `contentStream`.